# Recursion help in C++

Tags: c++, recursion

The assignment is Design and Develop a C++ program to list the first N terms of the Fibonacci series.

The output should look like this:

- N=2  1,1
- N=2  1,1
- N=3  1,1,2
- N=4  1,1,2,3
- N=5  1,2,3,5
- N=6  ....

My problem is that I have written the recursive function below but I'm not sure how to format it so it outputs to screen in the manner above.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Function Prototype
int fib(int);


int main()
{
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
    cout << fib(x) << " ";




    cin.get();
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

//Definition of fib 
int fib(int n)
{ 
//Return 1 when n is 0
 if ( n <= 0 ) 
     return 0;
 else if (n == 1)
     return 1;
 else
     return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);

}
```

Could someone shed some light on how to get this accomplished?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22949666/recursion-help-in-c

Comment: Thanks all.  You guys have been a great help in pointing me in the right direction.  I appreciate all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't care too much about efficiency, a double loop will do

```
for (int x = 2; x < 15; x++) {
  cout << "N = " << x << " ";
  for (int y = 2; y <= x; y++)
    cout << fib(y) << " ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it all does is print the fibonacci number, and the ones before, you just need to add them to your output ...
You can either have an aggregating string that you pass along, that will hold all the temp values, or just call another method that will have temp outputs. (mind you, it's not very efficient though :)

```
int fib_verbose(int n)
{ 
  //Return 1 when n is 0
   if ( n <= 0 ) 
      return 0;
  else if (n == 1) {         
      return 1;
  }
  else {
      int smaller = fib(n-2);
      int larger = fib(n-1);

      cout << smaller << " " << larger  << endl;
      return smaller + larger;
  }
}
```

You'll have to sort out the spaces, and formatting, but that's the gist.

**Edit:**
As per `agbinfo` comment: removed the `1` printing, and also storing the variables so we don't need to call them twice. (Still, for efficiency, look at Marius's answer :) ).

Comment: That won't work. The `cout << 1` doesn't help but more importantly, `fib_verbose(n-x)` will be executed recursively. You probably want `cout << fib_verbose(n-2) << fib(n-1);`

Answer (score 1):

How to format?

You have a good start.
Try this as a next step...

```
for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
   cout << x << "=" << fib(x) << " " << std::endl;

cin.get();
```

In my system, I can add to the cout line, compile, and review the output in < 10 seconds. Fast turn around and practice (for you) are your friends.

Comment: That would give you a 0-15 as the first items on each line, where the OP wants "N (fib_result_here) (fib partial results here)"

Comment: @Noctis - Thanks, I agree.  My goal was to encourage him to try, as he showed no attempt.  I also wondered if he understood what the table was supposed to show.  I probably should have just added a comment to his submission.  I consider it an ongoing problem to simply give the obvious students an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach. I'd save the already computed Fibonacci values so they are not computed them over and over again, like in a map, and than using that map to print the values.

```
std::map<int, int> fibs;

int fib(int const n)
{
   auto p = fibs.find(n);
   if(p != fibs.end())
      return p->second;

   int f = 1;
   if (n > 1)
   {
      f = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
   }

   fibs[n] = f;

   return f;
}
```

You can then loop through the computed values like this:

```
for(int n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
{
   fib(n);

   std::cout << "N=" << n << " ";
   for(int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
      std::cout << fibs[i] << ",";

   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That would save you the double runs and be more efficient (as my answer suggested, it wasn't aiming for efficiency).

Comment: Any reason for not using a `std::vector`?

Comment: It's just an example. Sure you can use a vector, but the relation between index and value might be a more complicated if you do not resize the vector from the beginning and push elements as you compute them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that doesn't recompute values when calling `fib` for a single value. You can combine Marius's idea to compute the values once even on multiple runs.

The trick is that `fib(unsigned&, unsigned)` will return the previous fibonacci it has already computed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned fib(unsigned& m, unsigned n)
{ 
  if (n==0) {
    return 0;
  }

  if (n==1) {
    m = 0;
    // cout << "0,"; // uncomment if sequence should start with a 0
    return 1;
  }

  unsigned prev;
  m = fib(prev, n-1);
  cout << m << ",";
  return m+prev;
}

unsigned fib(unsigned n) {
  unsigned prev;
  unsigned f = fib(prev, n);
  cout << f;
  return f;
}

int main() {
  for (unsigned i=2; i<13; i++) {
    cout << "N=" << i << " ";
    fib(i);
    cout << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Will printout:

```
N=2 1,1
N=3 1,1,2
N=4 1,1,2,3
N=5 1,1,2,3,5
N=6 1,1,2,3,5,8
N=7 1,1,2,3,5,8,13
N=8 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21
```

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN I think it does. It's not formatted exactly as requested but calling `fib(n)` does print the first `n` terms of the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: Updated to print table exactly as requested.